# Emulator stopped working on Android Studio failed to load memtrack module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I accidentally shut down my AS but luckily I had everything saved, when I reopened everything I added a small bit of code but nothing much at all. Now the emulator wont run my program. I am not sure if I accidentally changed a setting by quitting AS or if the extra bit of code is causing there to be not enough memory. I read someone had this problem and simply increased the RAM and it worked. How do you do this? or is there any other solutions?

Comment: Im pretty new to programming so my technical knowledge of Java and AS is very limited. Just wanted to add that the graph at the bottom of AS that runs while my app runs only shows the memory peaking at 3mb?? surely my app has more memory than that?

Answer (score 0):

If there something with emulator and AS best way to fix is restart computer)
If doesn't help delete emulator.
Yes you can increase Java heap size and it would improve not only emulator work but all Java the system.

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
```

Comment: How do I delete the emulator? I have been trying to uninstall it so that I can reinstall it but I cannot figure out how to do that. I tried restarting my computer but still the same problem. I have checked my memory usage and I definitely am not using too much.

Comment: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
 Debugger is no longer active
Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3ee7cf0, tid 2203
Validating map...
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3ee7d90, tid 2222
 Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 Enabling debug mode 0
 eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
 Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3f16c60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
diverY = 200
y = 200
 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3fff030, tid 2234

Comment: The memtrack module error isnt appearing anymore :/